# if G has a Hamilton cycle, then G also has a Hamilton path.

Tags: computational-complexity, hamiltonian-path

**How can I show that if G has a Hamilton cycle, then G also has a Hamilton path?**

From my understanding, I feel like we can show it by removing an edge that is connected from the end to the start of the cycle.

I'm completely new to this complexity theory and have been facing trouble understanding both of these. Can someone clear my confusion that is if my basic understanding of the solution is correct and guide me on how to solve it?

Comment: Yep, you just solved it. No need to make it more complicated than that.

Comment: @user786879 Thank You.